# Runtime parameters values in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, azure-pipelines, runtime, pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps Pipeline. As per our requirement we need pass the code base locations in parameters. and use that parameters and execute some files. and also we have multiple code base location.

**Ex :**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: targetLocation
    displayName: pathname ?
    type: string 

stages:
  - stage: Bashscript
    jobs:
      - job: 
        continueOnError: false     
        steps:
        - checkout: self

        - task: TerraformInstaller@2
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: 'latest'       
            
        - script: |
            **cd '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/project-creation/'**
            terraform init
            chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops/0.9.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.9.1
            terraform plan


        - script: |
            cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(path)
            terraform init
            chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops/0.9.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.9.1
            terraform plan


        - script: |
            ${{ parameters.targetDirectory }}
            terraform init
            chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops/0.9.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.9.1
            terraform plan
```

I tiried both items.

**ERROR :**

/home/vsts/work/_temp/sdsadasd-dsd-sds-b400-dfadfdasd.sh: line 1: workingDirectory:: command not found
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up your YAML like as below.

```yaml
trigger:
  - master

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
- name: targetLocations
  displayName: 'pathname ?'
  type: object
  default:
    - absolute/path/to/location_1
    - absolute/path/to/location_2
    . . .
    - absolute/path/to/location_N

stages:
  - stage: Bashscript
    jobs:
      - job: 
        continueOnError: false     
        steps:
        - checkout: self

        - task: TerraformInstaller@2
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: 'latest'       
        
        - ${{ each Location in parameters.targetLocations }}:
          - script: |
              terraform init
              chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops/0.9.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azuredevops_v0.9.1
              terraform plan
            workingDirectory: ${{ Location }}
```